# Запретить выполнение функций

Tags: jquery, функции

Доброго времени суток! как мне сделать так, чтобы если у элемента есть класс `disabled`, обработчики, навешанные на него не выполнялись?

Comment: Почему бы не добавить в самый вверх обработчик события?

   $(".disabled").on("click",function(e){
      alert("Вы нажали на кнопку");
      e.stopPropagination();
   });

   $(":button").on("click",function(){
      alert("Вы нажали на кнопку2");
   });

Comment: @eicto а почему тогда работает? http://jsbin.com/iRoYoQI/1/edit Ну хватит тереть комментарии!) Я же тоже как дурак выгляжу тогда))

Comment: :) я просто проверил и удалил комент :)

Comment: @lampa на самом деле работает только из-за того что у вас опечатка в 

**stopPropagination**  на самом деле
**stopPropagation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто добавьте ко всем селекторам :not(.disabled), когда навешиваете функцию, например так:

```
$("#gameboard").on("click", "td:not(.disabled)", handler);
```

Или так:

```
$("td:not(.disabled)").on("click", handler);
```

Comment: первый ваш вариант наверное наиболее рабочий

Comment: я там слегка ошибся `off` не сработает если хэндлер был задан так:

    $('body').on('click',selector,handler);

а off:

    $('.disabled').off('click');

т.е. если элемент на котором on  не равен элементу на котором .off

Comment: @eicto, ага, сталкивался с этим. Тогда либо вешать так:

    $(selector).on('click',handler);

либо, напротив, снимать отдельно, для каждого селектора:

    $('.disabled').off('click',selector);

Второй вариант означает кучу лишнего кода, так что лучше сразу

    $('.disabled').on('click',selector+":not(.disabled)",handler);

Comment: ещё есть вариант обернуть все свои хэндлеры в доп хэндлер который будет проверять наличие класса .disabled на currentTarget и this , но это оверкил мне кажется.

Answer (score 0):

видимо что-то типа такого:

```
$('.disabled').each(function(){
    $(this).unbind();
});
```

должна убивать все обработчики которые были повешаны на элементы до выполнения этого кода (надо бы протестить)

Comment: если в скобки передать название конкретного события ('click' к примеру), то должно оключиться выполнение только этого события

Comment: я думаю вопрос во временном удалении событий. так-то сработает  и 

    $('.disabled').off('click');

Comment: @zippp а если класс disabled динамический?

Comment: @lampa, если класс динамический, то используем то же делегирование:

    $('body').off('click', '.disabled');
    // или даже так
    $('.disabled').off('click', '**');

Comment: @Deonis не работает http://jsbin.com/iRoYoQI/2/edit

Comment: @lampa, Это jsbin какой-то не правильный )) А вообще, ХЗ чего оно так, ведь по всему должно работать. Надо будет учесть на будущее.

Comment: @eicto, я тоже об этом подумал (и даже написал), но нет:

    $('.disabled').off('click');

Снимет обработчики, навешанные только с помощью

    $('.disabled').on('click', handler);

Comment: @Risto я проверил, снимает все. по крайней мере в 1.9

http://jsfiddle.net/jDYdH/2/

Comment: @eicto, блин, ну вот же оно в чем дело)) @lampa, повесил на пример версию 1.8, поэтому и не сработало ;) А я уже думал, что баг какой-то.

Comment: @eicto, действительно, учту на будущее. Однако, это сработает только если функция вешалась через on(), а тогда проще вообще отсеивать .disabled при навешивании, как я и предложил.

Comment: @Deonis :-D да блин, одна неточность, одна ошибка. Пора домой.

Comment: @Risto это срабатывает всегда :)

@Deonis 

    $('body').off('click', '.disabled');

не работает и с 1.9 
http://jsfiddle.net/jDYdH/4/

> selector

> Type: String

> A selector which should match the one originally passed to .on() when attaching event handlers.

Comment: @eicto, off()? [Документация][1] с вами не согласна:

> Удаляет с выбранных элементов страницы обработчики событий, установленные с
> помощью метода .on().


  [1]: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Off

Comment: документация на jquery.com на остальных сайтах - вольный перевод или пересказ. я привел документацию [отсюда](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

в вашем источнике: 

> selector — селектор, **указанный** (если он был указан) **при установке события** в методе .on().

так-что даже здесь нет противоречия.

вообще `.off` конечно не навешивает новое "перехватывающие" событие, а просто отключает старое 

или вы про "только для .on" так сейчас все установщики через `.on` работают. в смысле `$(selector).click(handler) === $(selector).on('click',handler)` читайте сорцы

Comment: @eicto, [обязательно сработает][1] не только начиная с версии 1.9, но и в версиях 2.x, НО если была применена делегированная обработка, а не как в вашем примере, событие вешается непосредственно на элемент, что по сути очень близко к обычному синтаксису:

    $('selector').click(handler);

И естественно, что должен быть соблюден порядок применения методов.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/jDYdH/5/

Comment: @Risto если же вы говорите о `.addEventListener(handler)` и `.onclick=handler`, то это крайне не рекомендуемые способы устанавливать перехватчики событий в случае работы с jquery.

@Deonis ваш пример не имеет смысла, вы устанавливаете хэндлер на .disabled я про это и говорил, если делегирующий селектор не равен селектору в `.off` то не сработает. http://jsfiddle.net/jDYdH/7/

вот так работает, но это хак какой-то его @lampa придумал http://jsfiddle.net/jDYdH/8/

Comment: @eicto, далеко не все, к сожалению, используют on(): многие вешают обработчики стандартными средствами JS или применяют bind(), как @zippp, или live(). Также не стоит забывать про такой редкий, но полезный метод, как one(). Поэтому я и предложил универсальное решение, которое, к тому же, позволит не писать лишний раз off(), так как фильтрация по классу идёт уже в момент установки обработчика.

Хотя, если большинство обработчиков вешались через on(), то 

    $('.disabled').off();

Будет весьма удобен.